# Libstreaming issues in Android Lollipop(Moto G)

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, libstreaming

I did all the steps mentioned in the answer for this question 
([MediaRecorder issue on Android Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990816/mediarecorder-issue-on-android-lollipop),but) couldn't make my app run .It is throwing me "An error occurred while connecting to camera : 0" after I tried to play the stream with VLC. How to fix this issue ? Below is the log from my logcat .

```
04-19 18:13:33.986: D/VideoStream(13923): Video encoded using the MediaRecorder API
04-19 18:13:33.990: W/CameraBase(13923): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
04-19 18:13:33.991: E/RtspServer(13923): Fail to connect to camera service
04-19 18:13:33.992: W/System.err(13923): net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.exceptions.CameraInUseException: Fail to connect to camera service
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.openCamera(VideoStream.java:622)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.createCamera(VideoStream.java:632)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.encodeWithMediaRecorder(VideoStream.java:372)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.MediaStream.start(MediaStream.java:274)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoStream.start(VideoStream.java:312)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.H263Stream.start(H263Stream.java:68)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session.syncStart(Session.java:451)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspServer$WorkerThread.processRequest(RtspServer.java:506)
04-19 18:13:33.993: W/System.err(13923):    at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspServer$WorkerThread.run(RtspServer.java:390)
04-19 18:13:33.994: D/RtspServer(13923): RTSP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
04-19 18:13:33.994: D/RtspServer(13923): Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
04-19 18:13:33.994: D/RtspServer(13923): Cseq: 4
04-19 18:13:33.994: D/RtspServer(13923): Content-Length: 0
04-19 18:13:33.997: I/RtspServer(13923): Client disconnected
```

Comment: I have the same issue on Nexus 6 with Lollipop. Did you find a fix for the issue.

Comment: @Zlatko ,Nope not yet.