# Android: Video-streaming with Mediarecorder over Sockets using ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android, sockets, exception, streaming, android-mediarecorder

I'm struggling with this quiet long and I decided I need help.
The basis idea is described here: [Link](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system)

I want to stream the output from the MediaRecorder directly to my Server over Sockets while recording. (In this specific case I want to see if this is possible without using any streaming protocol just via a HTTP-POST.)

The error of my current approach is: **E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648 - RuntimeException**

Before I had an error pointing me to this topic [mediarecorder-issue-on-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27118142/8506154)

I use a AsyncTask class to call my recordData() function:

```
new sendAsync().execute("test");


private void recordData(Socket socket){
    try{
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = null;

        ParcelFileDescriptor[] parcelFileDescriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        parcelRead = new ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[0]);
        parcelWrite  = new ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[1]);
        try{
            is = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(parcelRead);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
        sft = new SurfaceTexture(0);
        sf = new Surface(sft);

        if(recorder == null) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(sf);

            recorder.setOutputFile(parcelWrite.getFileDescriptor());

            recorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // 10 seconds
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
                System.out.println("This is Recorder running");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int byteread = 0;
            while ((byteread = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            out.flush();
        }else{
            stopRecording();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the bad coding-style.

I tried to change the OutputFormat and VideoEncoder following other solutions found to the topic. But nevertheless I'm still not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Even after coming around this bug I think I somehow need to read out and send the Stream to the server in its own thread.

Every hint could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an error due to latest versions on Android (tested on Nougat and Oreo). But as much I tried to find a workaround I still ended up on the same error message with trying to use the MediaRecorder.
Thanks to libstreaming I use now the [MediaCodec API](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming#encoding-with-the-mediacodec-api) explained in their example how to use the Library: [Example 2](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples#example-2).

Then I take the Inputstream of the MediaCodec API and read it into a byte array until a certain size is reached and send this to my http-server.

Comment: do you have any example showing where you take inputstream? From example I don't understand which one to take data from